# Access item from a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got an ionic/angularjs app that i'm trying to get the last inserted ID of a SQLite, however whatever way I try I try and access the variable in the object of the promise comes back as undefined.

My promise is;

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, parameters)
        .then(function (result) {
          q.resolve(result);
        }, function (error) {
          console.warn('I found an error');
          console.warn(error);
          q.reject(error);
        });
    });
    return q.promise;
```

It's called by:

```
 self.addPicture = function(photo) {
    var parameters = [photo.base64];
    console.log("INSERT INTO AssetPhotos (id, base64) VALUES (NULL,?)", parameters);
    var id = DBA.query("INSERT INTO AssetPhotos (id, base64) VALUES (NULL,?)", parameters);
    return id;
  }
```

And then in the actual code:

```
 Assets.add($scope.addasset);
    var i = 0;
    for (pic in $scope.photos) {
      console.log(Assets.addPicture($scope.photos[i]));
        i++;
    }
```

However, it returns:

```
Promise {$$state: Object}
$$state: Object
status: 1
value: Object
insertId: 20
rows: Object
rowsAffected: 1
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Promise
```

(or to see it easier)

[image]

What i'm trying to achieve is that the console.log(Assets.addPicture($scope.photos[i])) just returns the insertId. I've tried adding .value.InsertId and .InsertId but forwhatever reason I just can't seem to get just the InsertId back to use it

**Edit:** I've updated the code to the following which looks right but I get an error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
$scope.addAsset = function(){
    Assets.add($scope.addasset);
    var i = 0;
    for (pic in $scope.photos) {
      Assets.addPicture($scope.photos[i])
      .then(res => console.log(res.insertId))
      i++;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot console.log() a Promise's return thing except inside of a .then. As I understand your code, this might work, or something similar:

```
Assets.add($scope.addasset);
var i = 0;
for (pic in $scope.photos) {
  Assets
    .addPicture($scope.photos[i])
    .then(res => console.log(res.insertId)) // logging out here
  i++;
}
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you - One more quick thing that code errors with a Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list but the brackets look fine to me

Comment: probably extra parens somewhere else then?

Comment: That would be the obvious answer, however I really can't see where

Comment: hm, I think you should find your own missing parens

Comment: I do agree, but honestly I can't see any missing. I do really appreciate the help

Comment: okay, well then debug - instead of es6 use normal javascript callback function. print out the result, see what happens? I've never used angular

Comment: and maybe get a linter